# Асинхронный map

Tags: node.js, async-await, backend

Пишу бекенд на node (v 8.11.4)

Сервер общается с vk api. У vk есть ограничение - 5 запросов с секунду.

Чтобы не уперется в ограничение было решено сделать функцию `sleep`:

```
export default (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

Далее есть мой метод (туда импортирую функцию `sleep`):

```
app.post(path, (req, res) => {
    [1,2,3].map(async item => {
        await sleep(1000);
        console.log(item);
    })
})
```

Здесь я ожидаю что `console.log` будет срабатывать раз в секунду. Но этого не происходит. Проходит 1 секунда и `console.log` выводится 3 раза.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все дело в том что этот код:

```
[1,2,3].map(async item => {
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(item);
})
```

Тоже самое что и этот

```
let foo = async item => {
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(item);
}

foo();
foo();
foo();
```

Все три функции вызываются сразу. Каждая ждет по секунде и затем одна за другой выводят item в консоль. Так как начинают ждать они одновременно, то и заканчивают тоже, поэтому вы видите что сообщения выводятся сразу все.

Можно сделать так:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const foo = async (item, i) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return console.log(item);
  }, 1000 * i); // 1000 - это ваша задержка между вызовами
}
numbers.map(foo);
```

Можно ставить устанавливать задержку после каждого вызова:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const delayLoop = (array, delay) => {
  let i = 0;
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(numbers[i]);
      if (++i < numbers.length) {
        loop();
      }
    }, delay);
  };
  loop();  
}
delayLoop(numbers, 1000);
```

Можно сделать пример выше более универсальным, добавив callback:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const delayLoop = (array, delay, handler) => {
  let i = 0;
  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      handler(numbers[i]);
      if (++i < numbers.length) {
        loop();
      }
    }, delay);
  };
  loop();  
}

const count = (value) => {
  console.log(`counter: ${value}`);
}
delayLoop(numbers, 1000, count);
```

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял инужно выводитьв консоль значения из массива с заданным интервалом, то можно сделать так -

```js
const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
const array = [1, 2, 3];

array.reduce(async(result, current) =>
  result.then(() => sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(current))), Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, такие циклы проще делать с помощью `for..of` циклов:

```js
app.post(path, async (req, res) => {
    for (const item of [1,2,3]) {
        await sleep(1000);
        console.log(item);
    })
})
```